# Cocos2D 2.0 - using CCSpriteBatchNode, CCMenuItem and CCmenu

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to reduce the number of OpenGL calls and memory usage, by using CCSpriteBatchNode.

I need to create a CCMenu using this code:

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"atlasGeral.png"];

CCSprite *inputNormal = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"normalInput.png"];
CCSprite *inputPressed = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"PressedInput.png"];
[batchNode addChild:inputNormal];
[batchNode addChild:inputPressed];


CCMenuItem *input = 
    [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:inputNormal
                           selectedSprite:inputPressed
                                   target:self 
                                 selector:@selector(InputMenu:)];
CCMenu *mInputMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:input, nil];
```

This is crashing catrastophically with the message **Assertion failure in -[CCMenuItemSprite addChild:z:tag:]**

any clues? BTW can someone create or point to some tutorial that explain decently how to use this CCSpriteBatchNode together with these other elements as CCMenus, CCMenuItems and other beauties? Cocos2D has zero documentation on barely all most important features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the inputNormal and inputPress sprites are children of the batch node. Thus, when you try to add them as child again to another node descendant, coco whines because they already have a parent. Cant be done I'm afraid. imnsho, batch nodes are grossly over rated. The improvement gain can only be reaped in very few and limited use cases.

Again, straight from CCMenuItemSprite code (version 1.0.1)

```
-(void) setNormalImage:(CCNode <CCRGBAProtocol>*)image
{
    if( image != normalImage_ ) {
        image.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        image.visible = YES;

        [self removeChild:normalImage_ cleanup:YES];
        [self addChild:image];

        normalImage_ = image;
    }
}
```

the menuitem tries to add the (already child) sprite to itself. No beans.

Comment: thanks. For what I see these CCSpriteBatchNode are far from being something really useful. They have a very limited use and a lot of problems. The only solution is, perhaps, to create my own CCMenu-like class!

Comment: CCSpriteBatchNode can be a huge performance saver if the images are either rather large, or if they're mostly scaled and rotated. Since sprite batch nodes have no other restriction than only allowing sprites as children, try to incorporate them into your design early on.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - agreed on the use case you mention, assuming you are not trying to interleave graphical objects from multiple textures at different zOrders in a layer. I may have missed how to add multiple batch nodes to a layer, yet have all children sprites be referenced to a unique z axis (the layer's).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D agreed!  In one project I was working on, I had a seven layered sprite.  without the batchnode being used to handle all of the images that made up those layers, the performance was atrocious.  That said, I was using them in my current project, but the fact that nodes in the batch node are not actually children of the visual parents that they are visual children of, means that actions on the visual parent such as scaling, position, etc are not then applied to the visual children.  This makes working with a batchnode far more complicated than it should be, which is a shame.